# Make: copy file from remote server rather than remake

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'd like to copy a file from a remote server rather than recompute it if possible when using gnu make. To do this I've been keeping a local "dummy" file which records (via timestamp) when the file was last created and copied *to* the remote server. The gist of what I want to do is below. `computed.file` is the file itself and `computed.file.remote` is the dummy.

```
computed.file: computed.file.remote
    <copy computed.file from remote server>

computed.file.remote:
    <command to create computed.file>
    <copy computed.file to remote server>
    touch computed.file.remote
```

However, this will force the file to be copied *to* and *from* the remote server if both rules are invoked, even though it exists when the file is created in the second rule.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I'm assuming that your `computed.file.remote` really has prerequisites that specify when it is out of date and should be re-copied.

Comment: Yes it does.   .   .   .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can do something like this:

```
computed.file: computed.file.remote
        if [ $< -nt $@ ]; then <copy computed.file from remote server>; fi

computed.file.remote:
        <command to create computed.file>
        <copy computed.file to remote server>
        touch -r computed.file $@
```